# First plot disappear when moving mouse wheel

Tags: gnuplot

I plot my data with multi-plot(two plots arraged by two rows one column ) by gnuplot5.2 in a script. And I get my plot perfectly--the completed plot is output to screen because I `set term win`.

But when I move mouse wheel in the window screen, the first plot(the upper one) disappeared and never come back again. Only the second plot remains on screen.

Does anyone meet the same problem? And anyone can help me finding back the disappeared plot on screen?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that moving the mouse wheel triggers a `replot` which only repeats the last plot command. Therefore I'm afraid that the disappeared plot can not be restored.

But it would be a nice feature.

*Update:*

If your subplots have the same ranges, you can try this (ugly) workaround. Split your script into two files like that:

```
# a.plt
reset
set xrange [0:pi]
set yrange [-1:1]

load "b.plt"
```

and

```
# b.plt
set multiplot layout 2,1
    plot sin(x)
    plot cos(x)
unset multiplot
```

Then, in the first run, start gnuplot and run `a.plt` with

```
load "a.plt"
```

And then, after each mouse wheel action, reload and run `b.plt` with

```
load "b.plt"
```

The two plots must have the same ranges because gnuplot remembers only the last settings, changes them according to your mouse wheel action, and applies them to both plots. In my opinion this is a limitation which renders the workaround nearly unusable.

Comment: Is there a way to block `replot`?